# How to make this files function non-recursive?

Tags: python, file, recursion, directory, operating-system

This is a function that lists all the files in the current folder and the subfolder which is recursive, I'm not able to write it non-recursively

I tried using while and for loops in nested format but I was not able to make it work.

```
def recur_files(start_dir):
    files = []
    original_path = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(start_dir)
    items = os.listdir()
    for item in items:
        if "." in item:
            files.append(os.path.abspath(item))
        else:
            files.extend(recur_files(os.path.abspath(item)))
    os.chdir(original_path)
    return files
```

Comment: use `os.walk()` to get all files in folder and subfodlers.

Comment: to make it without recursion (and without os.walk)you would have to use list for directories and use loop which gets dirname from this list. if it find subfolder then it add dirname to this list and next time loop should get it from list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list your files in a Depth First Search fashion without using the program stack (aka via recursion), you can always create your own stack (just a list in Python) and write a simple DFS algorithm as follows.

```
import os


def recur_files():
    original_path = os.getcwd()
    stack = os.listdir()
    results = []

    for item in stack:
        os.path.join(original_path, item)

    while stack:
        elem = stack.pop(0)
        if os.path.isdir(elem):
            results.append(elem)
            for item in os.listdir(elem):
                stack = [os.path.join(elem, item)] + stack
        else:
            results.append(elem)

    return results
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This taught me how to handle any recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

```
from os import walk

files = []
for _, _, filenames in walk(your_path):
    files.extend(filenames)
print("Files: {}".format(files))
```

You can get all files recursively in you path.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It satisfied my purpose. Highly greatful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.walk()` to get all files in folder and subfolders.

But if you want to create own function then you need list for dirs. Loop should get dirname from this list and you should add new dirs to this list instead of running function with new `start_dir`

```
import os

def recur_files(start_dir):
    files = []
    dirs = [start_dir]

    for dirname in dirs:
        for item in os.listdir(dirname):

            fullpath = os.path.join(dirname, item)

            if os.path.isdir(fullpath): #and fullpath not in ('.', '..'):
                dirs.append(fullpath)
            else:
                files.append(fullpath)

    return files, dirs

recur_files('.')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Very helpful. I will use os.walk(). I also learnt to convert recursive functions into a non-recursive one.